# Failing Spec for button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, testing, rspec

So I recently took on a project upgrading a Ruby 1.9.3 / Rails 3.2 application to Ruby 2 / Rails 4.0.2. All seems to be well, but I have a failing spec. I'm trying to test that a button is working at the bottom of the page for a "suggestions" box.

Failure message is:

```
Failures:

1) StaticPages Scheduler Page after authenticating filling in the suggestion form after submitting the form should send an email request with the form contents
 Failure/Error: click_button("suggestion-button")
 ActionController::UnknownFormat:
   ActionController::UnknownFormat
 # ./app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:39:in `suggestion'
 # ./spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb:93:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Spec reads:

```
context "after submitting the form" do
      before(:each) do
        click_button("suggestion-button")
      end
```

Controller reads:

```
def suggestion
if user_signed_in?
  user = current_user.email
else
  user = "< not logged in >"
end

if params[:suggestion]
  ContactMailer.suggestion_email(params[:suggestion], params[:pathname], user).deliver!
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: params[:suggestion] }
end
end
```

The source for the button on the page is:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" id="suggestion-button">
    Tell Us!
  </button>

</form>
```

```
<script>
  // After form submission, gray out and disable the form
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#footer-suggestion-form").bind("ajax:complete", function(event, xhr, status){
      console.log($("#footer-suggestion-form input"));
      $("#footer-suggestion-form input").attr("disabled","disabled");
      $("#footer-suggestion-form button").attr("disabled","disabled").html("Thanks!");
      console.log("did it!");
    });
    $("#suggestion-pathname").val(location.pathname);
  });
</script>
```

Is it because it's an AJAX form? Or just a test that worked in Rails 3.2 but no longer works in 4 because of some change? I appreciate any help, I am truly lost.

I did try using :js => true in the spec and downloading the capybara-webkit gem, but when I try to run the spec it gets to that test and then just hangs there waiting for something to happen that never does.

EDIT: Progress. Now it gets to that test, sits for a big, and then fails with

1) StaticPages Scheduler Page after authenticating filling in the suggestion form after submitting the form should send an email request with the form contents

Failure/Error: before { visit scheduler_path }

RuntimeError:
Rack application timed out during boot
./spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb:31:in `block (3 levels) in

Comment: Could you highlight line number:39 in `static_pages_controller.rb`?

Comment: 39: respond_to do |format|

Comment: Sounds like the ajax request is not properly executed. I would like to point you to an article about debugging such issues yourself http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: Here's a gist of the controller and spec file: https://gist.github.com/zkay/8366949

Comment: This is still unsolved. I made progress by installing the webkit JS driver for capybara and database_cleaner. Now it gets to that test, seems to hang for a while, and then fails with     

RuntimeError:       Rack application timed out during boot